# How to change speed of rotation in .php file

Tags: php, wordpress, rotation, duration, testimonials

Here is my testimonials.php file below. I would like to change the speed of the rotation of testimonials, however I am unsure what code to write in. Your assistance is appreciated!

```
    <?php
/**
 * Testimonials
 *
 */
 ?>
<div class="testimonials sixteen columns alpha omega marT20 marB40 padT40 padB20">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'testimonial', 
            'order' => 'DSC',
            'posts_per_page' => 100
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

    <ul class="testimonial-content">

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <h5 class="marB8"><?php the_content(); ?></h5>
            <h5 class="marB0"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h5>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is likely related to the JavaScript controlling the rotation rather than the PHP generating the HTML.

Comment: `speed of the rotation of testimonials` would assume that Javascript was involved here. Can you explain?

Comment: We would like to help but can explain in more detail - 
What exactly do you mean by "I would like to change the speed of the rotation of testimonials"

Comment: I have searched for a corresponding JS file but been unsuccessful. I thought perhaps there wasn't one and the rotation function could be altered here. Is that not the case?

Comment: It's not the case here. You can't really do this kind of thing with PHP. There's a JS File somewhere that's controlling it.

Comment: "I would like to change the speed of the rotation of testimonials" this post operates a cycle of testimonials on my site. Currently the way it is set up, they cycle too quickly and I need to slow them down so the visitor can actually read them. Can this be done here or do I need to find a corresponding JS file?

Comment: I think that's the wrong section of php code. You should try to find something that begins with a "<script" tag.

Comment: No, that is not the case. This code is probably utilizing "The Loop" to fetch _all_ testimonials from WordPress, but then some JavaScript elsewhere (take a look at all the ``<script src="..."></script>`` tags in the head _and_ body sections) displays the testimonials one at a time, _after_ loading them. Find the script.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the class name, `testimonial-content`, you're probably using the WordPress testimonial widget. Check out the last setting here:

[image: Testimonials Widget Screenshot]

If you need to change this programmatically, then track down where it's used in the code, somewhere in `/wp-content/plugins/testimonials-widget/`.